# How to change date format in a zoo object?

Tags: r, zoo

A very simple question. But I just cannot find the solution via Google.

I have a quarterly zoo object named 'data' with date format "1947-4-1".

How can I change the date format into '1947 Q1'?

Answer (score 4):

OK

I got my own answer:

```
index(data)<-as.yearqtr(index(data))
```